# Missing type specifier On a Templated List Class using Templated Nodes

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, data-structures, compiler-errors

This is the Contents of Graph.h  without the header protects and other Functions

```
template <class T> class Node{
public:
    T data;
    Node<T> *NextNode;
public:
    Node();
    Node(T a);
    T getValue();
    void setValue(T a);
    void chainNode(Node<T> a);
    void chainNode(Node<T> *a);
    Node<T> getNextNode();
    void unchainNode();
};
//related methods
template <class T> Node<T>::Node(){
    data = NULL;
    NextNode = NULL;
}    
template <class T> void Node<T>::chainNode(Node<T> a){
    NextNode = NULL;
    NextNode = &a;
}
template <class T> void Node<T>::chainNode(Node<T> *a){
    NextNode = NULL;
    NextNode = a;
}    

template <class T> class List{
public:
    Node<T> *Head;
    List(Node<T> a);
    void AddInFront(Node<T> a);
    void AddInFront(Node<T> *a);
    void Append(Node<T> a);
    bool Remove(Node<T> a);
    bool Remove(T a);
    bool Contains(T a);
    bool DeleteList();
};
//Only working method of List
template <class T> List<T>::List(Node<T> a){
Head = &a;
}
// Error occurs in this Function
template <class T> List<T>::AddInFront(Node<T> a){
    a.chainNode(Head);
    Head = NULL;
    Head = &a;
}
```

And this is My Main

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Graph.h"
int main(){
    Node<int> a = Node<int>(20);
    List<int> d = List<int>(a);
    Node<int> b = Node<int>(20);
    d.AddInFront(b);
}
```

And here is my error

```
error C4430: Missing type specifier - int assumed . Note: C++ does not support default-  int
```

My compiler (MSVS 11) tells me I have a C4430 error at the end of the AddInFront function and by end I mean it is saying the line with anything but the end curly bracket has the error.I have tried every thing under the moon to try to get rid of this error but I just can't seem to fix it.

Comment: By the way, `Node<int> a(20);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to specify the return type in the definition of your `AddInFront()` function:

```
template <class T> void List<T>::AddInFront(Node<T> a) {
//                 ^^^^
//                 This was missing
    a.chainNode(Head);
    Head = nullptr;
    Head = &a;
}
```

Also notice, that the copy-initializations belows:

```
Node<int> a = Node<int>(20);
List<int> d = List<int>(a);
Node<int> b = Node<int>(20);
```

Are unnecessary. Rather use direct initialization:

```
Node<int> a(20);
List<int> d(a);
Node<int> b(20);
```

Comment: Wow I feel really dumb for asking this now... Thank you so much